# Creating Qt app targeted to different Linux distros

Tags: linux, qt

I’ve been tasked with getting our Qt app (which currently runs on Windows and Mac) to run on both Centos 5 & 6. What is the best way to go about doing this? I’ve been trying to get it to build on Centos 5 but the Qt isn’t very up to date. So I’d like to use Centos 6, but can I build a single binary that will run on both 5 & 6, using Qt v4.8 and its version of Qt Creator? It would be ideal, of course, if this same binary would also run on other distros, like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and here are my thoughts about it:

- link staticly against the Qt libraries. First of all, only feasible if your application is open source OR you have a commercial license for Qt - otherwise you'll run into the LGPL linking exceptions.  In order to have static libraries to link against, you will have to build Qt yourself and configure it to generate static libs. Of course, you build Qt on the lowest denominator (i.e. CentOS 5) and pray that it works on CentOS 6 (it will).
- link dynamically against Qt libraries that you provide. You will have to make sure that the application takes the libraries that you provide, so don't forget to set the library search path for the application to start with the directory your libs are in. Again, you will have to build the Qt libraries yourself (on CentOS 5) and distribute them alongside your app.